# Can you identify this connector

Tags: electrical, part-identification

Trying to idendify this connector?

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Moab I think it would be fair for you to convert your comment to an answer. It seems to cover all the bases.

Comment: It's not a weatherpack connector, thanks though. Closest I can find is a Sumitomo MT-2S-7 but not sure....

Answer (score 2):

This connector is Sumitomo 6195-0062

Answer (score 1):

Its a standard 2 prong weatherpack connector used for many applications and sensors. that one appears to be common for fuel injectors on some american cars.

Answer (score 1):

Closest I have been able to find is a Sumitomo MT-2S-7 but it may be another brand, hoping someone knows for sure. There are no identifying marks.

Comment: Do we know what it's for? Any other background information?

Comment: I have been un-able to find one myself, the closest is the sumitomo. Is this off a motorcycle? My honda motorcycle uses this connector and a 3 hole one.

Comment: No, it's a Yamaha watercraft. I was able to find somewhere to order a Sumitomo sample so I should be able to confirm in a few days. Im hoping it's right but not confident.